# If a "foreach" iteration locks me from editing the actual item (a textbox line in this case), what is the work around?

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm going through each line as so:

```
foreach (string line in textBox1.Lines)
```

And if it matches a certain regex pattern, I want to get rid of the newline/carriage return at the end of the line so as to actually "merge" both lines into one like hopefully this would work:

> string replacement = Regex.Replace(line, @"\t|\n|\r", "");

But of course I get this error:

"Cannot assign to 'line' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'"

because I can't edit the actual line within a foreach iteration.

Full code which is probably wrong on multiple levels since I haven't been able to test it yet:

```
  foreach (string line in textBox1.Lines)
        {
            Regex regexFix = new Regex(@"\s+\d+$",
                RegexOptions.Compiled | 
        RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
            Match match = regexFix.Match(line);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                //do nothing for now
            }



            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("false" + line);
                string replacement = Regex.Replace(line, @"\t|\n|\r", "");


                line = line.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');


            }
```

Comment: "Of course"? You didn't show any code that _does_ assign to the `line` variable, so it's not clear why you'd get that error. You should show a complete code example that actually illustrates what you're trying to do and in what way it fails to work. There's nothing in your question that does that right now.

Comment: Thanks I saw that in a search but wasn't sure how to do a for loop that still went through each line in the same way a foreach does?

Comment: added the full code sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple `for` loop as suggested:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    textbox1.Lines[i] = "smth";
}
```

Comment: You can't merge lines this way - you need to use `TextBox.Text` + `string.Split` + `string.Join` OR `TextBox.Text` + `Regex.Replace`

Comment: Thanks vsevolod and alexei

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
foreach (string line in textBox1.Lines.ToList())
```

This creates a copy of your Lines object, so it's no longer locked.  However, it's not the most efficient means.